# Windows Process and Ip Address that it's connected to

Tags: c#, .net, windows, network-programming

I'm trying to get the ipaddress that a process is connected to in c#. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking for. Processes are not connected, sockets are and those are created by processes. Can you be more specific? Are you looking for something like the netstat tool with the -b parameter?

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to achieve this:

1. Use the undocumented `InternalGetTcpTableWithOwnerModule` / `InternalGetUdpTableWithOwnerModule` / `InternalGetTcp6TableWithOwnerModule` / `InternalGetUdp6TableWithOwnerModule` APIs exported from iphlpapi.dll.
2. Run `netstat -b` and parse the output.

Either way you will need administrator privileges and both ways are bound to break with different Windows versions. It is most certainly possible to create a Windows driver with documented APIs, but that would be a lot of work.

**Update:**

There is actually a documented API too - [GetExtendedTcpTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365928(VS.85).aspx) and [GetExtendedUdpTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365930(VS.85).aspx). Also there's an [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/iphlpapi2.aspx) which presents an example how to call it from C#.

Comment: This is working great, although the process in question is call of duty 4, and even when I'm in a server playing the game it doesnt ever appear in the list which is a little confusing.

Comment: Follow up, it's not even coming out in netstat -b

Comment: Do you know which protocol is Call of Duty using for the network connection? Does netstat -a -b show it?

Comment: Well it's coming back as UDP : 0.0.0.0:49404, but the initial address is 78.111.229.123:32000 which is tcp I believe, yet I never see that address.

Comment: Just used a packet sniffer and it's going to 78.111.229.123:32000 UDP

Comment: Then GetExtendedUdpTable should be able to return it, as long as the application is running with Administrator privileges. Does it report other UDP connections? Or is just this one missing?