# In Windows, how do I find out which process is on the other end of a local network socket?

Tags: windows, sockets, process, localhost

That is to say, if I have a server listening on 127.0.0.1, and a TCP connection comes in, how can I determine the process id of the client?

Also if there isn't an API for this, where would I be able to extract the information from in a more hackish manner?

(The purpose of this is to modify a local HTTP proxy server to accept or deny requests based on the requesting process.)

**Edit: palacsint's answer below led me to find [this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414740/windows-process-and-ip-address-that-its-connected-to) which is just what's needed**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
netstat -a -o
```

prints it. I suppose they are on the same machine becase you are listening on 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Thanks that helps immensely, from your answer and a bit of searching I found this question that indicates the APIs used for this, which is just what I need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414740/windows-process-and-ip-address-that-its-connected-to

Answer (score -1):

The only way to do this is if the connecting process sends some sort of custom headers which contains identifier. This is due to the fact that the networking layer is completely separated from the application layer (hint: [OSI MODEL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model). This way it is possible to write lower layers software without caring what happens above as long as the messages exchanged (read: networking packets) follow a pre-determined format (read: use the same protocol).

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this surely cannot be the only way. Somewhere on the system, the information is stored, so it must be possible to retrieve it somehow, even if it does mean disregarding theoretical separation of layers.

Comment: But what your proxy server is getting is essentially some network packets, it doesn't care whether the remote process is running on windows, linux, solaris etc or if it running on the local machine or not. Also pids are completely unreliable they don't hold any information whatsoever - they are random on each run so you can't hardcode them or built filters consisting of PIDS

Comment: This would only be for local connections, so processes that are connected to 127.0.0.1. Server listens on 127.0.0.1, connection comes in, server somehow determines process id that is doing the connection, then is able to look up process name, path, etc. from the process id and create a response accordingly.